# How do I acheive this effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, cs6, photoshop-effects

I beleive that this Image is edited version. I want to know how I can acheive this effect in Photoshop CS6? Any ready made effect action?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: "Imgur is over capacity. Try again in a few minutes" :)

Comment: @Scott the image was huge a little bit, I believe not it has fixed.

Comment: @Scott Image is loading fine

Comment: Okay.. it's loading now.. so..what "effect' are you referring to?

Comment: I believe it's just basic color ajdusting and maybe blurring the background a bit. It also seems to be a bit darkened

Comment: @RizwanKhan I rolled back your edit because removing the image makes the question and answers obsolete. Were you removing because of a copyright issue?

Comment: Voting to close because OP never came back to clarify what effect is the question about.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Add a new blank layer at the top
2. Fill it with white
3. Lower its opacity to yield the flared look on the side you want, say on the left like this, ignore what happens on the rest
4. Add a layer mask, fill it with gradient fill from black to white starting where you want the effect to start diminishing

See the images below which show before, after, and the layers palette.

[image: Layers stack]

[image: Before]

[image: After]